# Plotting density map in square kilometers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, density

I need to plot a lighting flash density per square km in a country map using ArcMap 10.8.

I have the shapefile (shp) of the map and I have the lightning flash data with location (longitude, latitude). I used density point function in the ArcGIS and I don't know how to convert the density to per square km. I changed the unit of my map from Decimal Degree to kilometers. I wanted to change the Area Unit in the Dot Density to square km but it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Point Density](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/point-density.htm) documentation, if you leave the Map Projection in Meters, the Point Density tool's default output area unit is Square_Kilometers. So I would change the map back to meters and make sure the Shapefile correctly has its linear units set to meters, which is the default for a Decimal Degrees projection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I leave or convert the Map Projection in Meters? Here is my shapefile info: Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: If you didn't do anything to that shapefile, such as ProjectDefine on it, then the GCS_WGS_1984 linear units will be meters.  Some Shapefiles have missing or incomplete projection details, though.  TIP: add the shapefile to a new map, then check the map's projection as it always adopts the projection of the first layer added.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I still cannot plot the point density in SQUARE_KILOMETERS. I don't know where to see ProjectDefine in the shapefile. I was able to set the Coordinate System of my shapefile from GCS_WGS_1984 to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere through the Layer (in the Table on content), and I was able to the unit to meters from Decimal degrees. I imported the lightning data which has Latitude, Longitude and lightning magnitude. But I was not able to display the XY data (Latitude and Longitude) of the lightning counts on the shapefile.

Comment: If I don't convert the Geographic Coordinate Systems of the shapefile to Projected Coordinate Systems, I am able to plot the density map, however the unit will appear in decimal degree.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like XY lightning data needs to be exported as a shapefile, then that lightning shapefile needs to have the same Coordinate System assigned.

Comment: Also, i appologize about ProjectDefine, I meant ProjectAssign...or the tool to assign a projection to an FC or shapefile without one. I use the tool when assigning projections to shapefiles because it writes the .prj file alongside the .sh* files in the folder.

Comment: I finally got the data converted Projected Coordinate Systems (GCS_WGS_1984 to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere), same as the Shapefile, through Project. Thank you so much for your help.